# Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.4.1 because no repositories are defined

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I created a multimodule spring boot, every module use spring.

My nvoice build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

allprojects {

    group = 'com.torenda'
    sourceCompatibility = '11'
}



subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'java'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

}

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}
```

settings.gradle of nvoice

```
rootProject.name = 'nvoice'

include ':invoice'
include ':payment'
```

build.gradle of my invoice module

```
description = 'invoice'


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

bootJar {
    enabled = true
}
```

When I try to build the app I get

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':bootRunMainClassName'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':detachedConfiguration1'.
> Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.4.1 because no repositories are defined.
> Required by:
> project :

Like you can see, repositories is definined in the main gradle file and i added it in the subprojects section too

Answer (score 1):

It works if you move repositories under allprojects and remove buildscript:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

allprojects {

    group = 'com.torenda'
    sourceCompatibility = '11'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'java'
}

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}
```